# How to achieve small grids for products in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi i'm making an android application where i have to make a product's section and i'm trying to make similar to quicker app So here is the problem i know i can you use gridview to make products section but i dont know how to add dotted borders between products or make grids smaller in size so i wanted to know if there is a better way to achieve this.
Any suggestions are welcome.
I saw this question on SO for products
[show products list in android with multicolumn custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675561/show-products-list-in-android-with-multicolumn-custom-layout)
But what i'm trying is to make small grids for products with no space and with dotted borders so if anyone have suggestions please let me know

Comment: Any picture with the preview what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to add images but you may have seen goibibio or quicker app where they show the products and we select from them so i'm confused which view i should use inorder to make that

Answer (score 0):

For dotted borders you can create new XML file inside drawable and put this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:color="@color/black"
        android:width="2dp"
        android:dashGap="5dp"
        android:dashWidth="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then in your single item parent layout set:

```
android:background="@drawable/name_of_your_dotted_borders_xml"
```